# Alterar valor de inteiro para string ou inserir máscara

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função que faz uma contagem, só que preciso adicionar máscara a este valor. O valor final é de 3000 só que preciso por 3.000;

há como alterar o valor de inteiro para outro formato e fazer mesmo assim a contagem dentro da própria função?

Segue função:

```js
function numerosHome(id, inicialValor, valorFinal){
  var inicial = inicialValor;
  var location = document.getElementById(id);
  var contador = setInterval(() => {
      location.innerHTML = inicial;
      inicial++;
      var final = valorFinal +1;
      if(inicial == final){
          clearInterval(contador);
      }
  },0.5);
}
numerosHome('numeros', 2800, 3000);
```

```css
#numeros{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numeros">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), dessa forma você vai trabalhar melhor com a formatação de números ou moedas.

```js
function numerosHome(id, inicialValor, valorFinal){
  var inicial = inicialValor;
  var location = document.getElementById(id);
  var contador = setInterval(() => {
      location.innerHTML = inicial.toLocaleString("pt-br");
      inicial++;
      var final = valorFinal +1;
      if(inicial == final){
          clearInterval(contador);
      }
  },0.5);
}
numerosHome('numeros', 2800, 3000);
```

```css
#numeros{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numeros">
</div>
```